# returning a list of dictionaries from Flask to Ajax/Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

I want Flask to return a **list** of dictionaries, where each dictionary has the following structure:

```
{'category': 'Spas/beauty/personal care', 'location': [48.84014, 2.26351], 'id': '161608194188848', 'zip': 'Tel:0777034152', 'state': '', '_id': ObjectId('57a9a8582daf236574089796'), 'street': '166 avenue de Versailles', 'category_list': [{'name': 'Aesthetics', 'id': '146053955462002'}], 'name': 'The bar à sourcils', 'city': 'Paris', 'country': 'France'}
```

I tried very methods, and the main error messages that I encountered are:

- `'dict' object has no attribute 'serialize'`: when I try to serialize the dictionaries inside the list.
- `ObjectId(...) is not JSON serializable`: when I try to use JSONIFY or json.dumps().

Here is the flask code:

```
@app.route('/getme', methods=['POST'])
def receiveData():
    curPos = request.json # curPos = {'lat': , 'lng': }
    client = MongoClient()
    db = client.places
    fbplacesCollection = db.fbplaces
    query = {'location': {'$geoWithin': {'$center': [[curPos['lat'], curPos['lng']], 0.089992801]}}}
    result = list(fbplacesCollection.find(query))
    return ' ' # I want to send the list called result
```

And here is the Ajax/Jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "getme",
      contentType:"application/json",
      dataType:"json",
      data: JSON.stringify(toSend)
    })
      .done(function( msg ) {
        // do s.th with the received msg
        console.log(msg);     
      });
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**I found a solution:**

Add the following to the flask code:

```
from bson.json_util import dumps
...
dumps(result)
return (result)
```

**Note:** Because MongoDB is storing document in **BSON** files, the *json.dumps()* will not work. *json_util* – Tools for using Python’s json module with BSON documents – will do this type of work. see http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html .

Cheers!